# Istio (1.2.2) - Same port, different paths with different policies

Tags: istio

I have 2 api within one application served on different paths (same port)

- /base
- /base/jclient/remoting

I'm trying to apply standard JWT authentication policy to /base/jclient/remoting but not /base

I've set up standard gateway and the following Virtual Service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: jm-gateway-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - jm-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /base/jclient/remoting
    route:
    - destination:
        host: jclient-remoting
        port:
          number: 8080
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /base
    route:
    - destination:
        host: jm-cc-service
        port:
          number: 8080
```

The services are setup as...

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jm-cc-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http-jm-cc-service
  selector:
    app: jm-cc-pod
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jclient-remoting
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http-jclient-remoting
  selector:
    app: jm-cc-pod
---
```

Destination rules...

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: jclient-remoting
spec:
  host: jclient-remoting
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: jm-cc-service
spec:
  host: jm-cc-service
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
---
```

...and finally the policies...

```
---
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: jclient-remoting
spec:
  targets:
  - name: jclient-remoting
  peers:
  - mtls: {}
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "https://xxx-jm.eu.auth0.com/"
      jwksUri: "https://xxx-jm.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
---
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: jm-cc-service
spec:
  targets:
  - name: jm-cc-service
  peers:
  - mtls: {}
---
```

No matter what I do both paths give "Origin authentication failed." but I would expect the /base/jclient/remoting to give "Origin authentication failed." but not the /base path?

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was approaching the problem in the wrong way. It does not make sense creating 2 services that hit the same pods.

I only need 1 service. Then in the policy add a trigger rule so the policy only applies for a specific path

```
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: jm-cc-service
spec:
  targets:
  - name: jm-cc-service
  peers:
  - mtls: {}
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "https://xxx-jm.eu.auth0.com/"
      jwksUri: "https://xxx-jm.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
      trigger_rules:
      - included_paths:
        - prefix: /base/jclient/remoting
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Cheers